# ASP.NET MVC 4 Validation Errors not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, validationsummary

All my routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Login",
        url: "{eid}/Login",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", eid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Congress_Code"] } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Account",
        url: "{eid}/Account/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "{action}", eid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Congress_Code"] }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{eid}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", eid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Congress_Code"] }
    );
```

In manage.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { eid = ViewBag.EventId }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

In the account controller:

```
//
// GET: /Account/Manage
//[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Manage(int eid, ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage =
        (message == ManageMessageId.UpdateDetailsObjSuccess) ? "Your user details have been modified."
        : "";
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Manage
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(UpdateUserDetailsModel model,int eid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var updateModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Models.UpdateUserDetailsModel,KPAD_Api.Kiosk.KioskUserDetailsExtended>(model);
        try
        {
            long token = Proxy.Proxy.Instance.Token[KioskUser.Id];
            var result = Proxy.Proxy.Instance.KioskUserClient.UpdateKioskUser(updateModel, token);
            if (result.ErrorCode == ReturnCodes.Codes.ALL_OK)
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.UpdateDetailsObjSuccess });
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError(ReturnCodes.Instance.GetMessage(result.ErrorCode), new Exception(ReturnCodes.Instance.GetMessage(result.ErrorCode)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Database error occured.Please contact the website administrator", e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("An unknown error occurend. Please try again. If it persists please contact the admin.",new Exception("Unknown"));
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

But still the validation summary doesn't show when I generate an exception on purpose or when it happens by nature.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In manage.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { eid = ViewBag.EventId }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

In controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(UpdateUserDetailsModel model,int eid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var updateModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Models.UpdateUserDetailsModel,KPAD_Api.Kiosk.KioskUserDetailsExtended>(model);
        try
        {
            long token = Proxy.Proxy.Instance.Token[KioskUser.Id];
            var result = Proxy.Proxy.Instance.KioskUserClient.UpdateKioskUser(updateModel, token);
            if (result.ErrorCode == ReturnCodes.Codes.ALL_OK)
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.UpdateDetailsObjSuccess });
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError(ReturnCodes.Instance.GetMessage(result.ErrorCode), new Exception(ReturnCodes.Instance.GetMessage(result.ErrorCode)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Database error occured.Please contact the website administrator");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("","An unknown error occurend. Please try again. If it persists please contact the admin.");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

it's bind the error in key- value pair.